# How does Samsung Wi-Fi password sharing work?

Tags: samsung, wi-fi, wifi-password

Every article I find mentioning how to share a Wi-Fi password between Android devices either mentions using a QR code, or clicking a "nearby share" button.

But when I enter the password for a new Wi-Fi network on my Galaxy phone, my Galaxy tablet connects automatically to the same network, without any action on my part. No QR code nor button pressing. And this happens while the tablet has no internet access.

What mechanism is making this happen? Is this something that I enabled and I don't remember, or does it happen by default?

Comment: What accounts (Google/Samsung/other) are setup on both devices?

Comment: Both devices have the same Google and Samsung accounts.

Comment: Maybe by [Wifi sharing creating a hotspot](https://tunecomp.net/wi-fi-sharing-on-samsung-galaxy/) that is specific to Samsung devices? (I don't own any)

Comment: If this is the case, you can write up an answer

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this answer was based on the original revision with an assumption that the other Samsung device already had an internet connection through another method.*

---

**Samsung Cloud provides several sync features to all Samsung Galaxy devices linked to the same Samsung account, *including Wi-Fi profiles.***

From [Samsung Support - Sync data across all of your devices using Samsung Cloud](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00060641/),

> You can make sure your phone's data is up-to-date with Samsung Cloud. It will sync data on multiple devices, so they'll have the latest information. For example, if you added a new Calendar event or contact on your phone, they will appear on other devices that are signed into the same Samsung account.

From [Samsung Support - Back up and restore data or files on your Galaxy device](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00060517/)

> #### Content types that can be backed up using Samsung Cloud
>
> - [...]
> - **Settings:** Accessibility settings, ringtones, Samsung Keyboard options, Wi-Fi settings, and Always on Display settings (your default ringtone won't be backed up)
> - [...]

[image]

From [Samsung Support - Access your device backups in Samsung Cloud](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00060518/)

> #### Access and manage the Cloud from a Galaxy phone or tablet
>
> Samsung Cloud is integrated directly into your Samsung account, so you can access it easily from your phone or tablet's settings.
>
> 1. Navigate to and open **Settings**.
> 2. Tap **your name** at the top of the screen, and then tap **Samsung Cloud**.
> 3. From here, you can access the following options:
>
> - **Sync:** Choose which apps or settings you'd like to automatically sync to Samsung Cloud, such as Contacts or Samsung Notes.
> - [...]
>
> #### Access the Cloud from a web browser on a PC
>
> 1. To access Samsung Cloud on your computer, open your desired web browser, and then go to **https://support.samsungcloud.com**.
> 2. Click **Sign in**, enter your Samsung account information, and then click **Sign in** again.
> 3. If you're unsure of your account information, click **Find ID or Reset password** after you click Sign in.
> 4. Once you are signed in, you can see all of your synced data.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Or, I guess the question is: how does my tablet connect to Samsung Cloud without the wifi password, to get the wifi password?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the situation because I assumed your Samsung tablet already had an internet connection through another method, like mobile data for example. Otherwise, I'm not sure either whether Samsung has some kind of active sync through another method (perhaps the other possibility is through Bluetooth)

Comment: Yeah, that's what my question is about. My tablet, with no internet connection, learns the wifi password (and connects to the network) a few seconds after my phone does.